# Convert char* string to upper

Tags: c, string, char

Following code is supposed to return the upper case string of the source.
It works but does not convert the string. Could not figure out what was wrong.

```
char *StrUpper (char *s) {
    int i = 0;
    char *t = &s [i];
    while (*t) {
        if ((*t > 0x5a) && (*t < 0x7b)) t = (t - 32);
        t = &s [i++];
    }
    return (s);
}

int main () {
    printf ("%s\n", StrUpper ("lower case string"));
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: 'it works but does not convert the string' - surely this means it _doesn't_ work?

Comment: Also to add that the reason why you say that it works is because you are getting an undefined behavior.

Comment: It might be good to mention that you're looking at the 0th element twice: `t = &s [i++]` might want to be replaced with `t = &s [++i]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string literal is a constant pointer to an array of constant characters. In other words, string literals are *read only*.

Trying to modify constant data leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). And if your program have *undefined behavior*, nothing about its behavior can be trusted at all.

Comment: I've already tried the code below, no change:
`
int main () {
    char *s = "lower case string";
    printf ("%s\n", StrUpper (s));
    return (0);
}`

Comment: @merkez3110 That's because `s` still *points* to the constant string literal. Instead do `char s[] = "...";`

Comment: OK! `StrUpper ("blah blah");` and `char *s = "blah blah"; StrUpper (s);` does not work; but `char s [] = "blah blah"; StrUpper (s);` works. Thanks for everyone. As @JoachimPileborg noted, I was trying to crunch a string literal which is a const by def.

Comment: Oddly enough, string literals are _not_ const by definition, they are non-modifiable by definition. String literals are exceptional: they don't become arrays of `const char` type, they become arrays of `char` type that you are nevertheless forbidden to modify.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems in your code:

1. You forgot to dereference the string in the assignment:

   ```
   t = (t - 32);
   ```

   should be

   ```
   *t = (*t - 32);
   ```
2. You don't check the correct range:

   ```
   if ((*t > 0x5a) && (*t < 0x7b))
   ```

   should be

   ```
   if ((*t > 0x6a) && (*t < 0x7b))
   ```

   or, even better

   ```
   if ((*t >= 'a') && (*t <= 'z'))
   ```
3. You go over the first character twice:

   ```
   t = &s [i++];
   ```

   should be

   ```
   t = &s [++i];
   ```

   or simply

   ```
   t++;
   ```

Comment: I've already tried that (*t = *t - 32) thing; in that case however, codeblock crashes like:
    Problem signature:
    Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
    ...
    Exception Code: c0000005

Answer (score 0):

you might also want to change

```
  t = &s[i++];
```

to

```
t =  &s[++i];
```

because , i++ first assigns current i value to the index then performs the increment, you end up processing the same index over again the first time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all these two statements

```
if ((*t > 0x5a) && (*t < 0x7b)) t = (t - 32);
t = &s [i++];
```

has no sense.

This expression statement

```
t = (t - 32);
```

changes the pointer itself. And this statement

```
t = &s [i++];
```

does not change the pointer at once.

Moreover it is not clear what these magic numbers,  0x5a, 0x7b, 32 mean.

The function could be written like

```
char * StrUpper ( char *s ) 
{
    for ( char *p = s; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( *p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z' ) *p -= 'a' - 'A';
    } 

    return s;
}
```

Here is an example of using the function

```
#include <iostream>

char * StrUpper ( char *s ) 
{
    for ( char *p = s; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( *p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z' ) *p -= 'a' - 'A';
    } 

    return s;
}

int main() 
{
    char s[] = "hello";

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << StrUpper( s ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
hello
HELLO
```

Take into account that some coding systems do not guarantee that all lower case letters follow each other without intermediate codes. So in general this approach is not correct.

Comment: Just tried your code above, codeblocks crashes like:

Problem Event Name: APPCRASH

Exception Code: c0000005

Comment: @merkez3110 The problem is not with the function I showed. The problem with how you call it. For example you may not use string literals as arguments of the function.

Comment: @@merkez3110  See my updated post where there is an example of using the function.